# Iphone calendar integrating problem

Tags: iphone, icalendar

I am integrating calendar to my application , after adding calendar i am getting error  , please help me anyone where it is problem .

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_KalViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-KalViewController in FertilityAppAppDelegate.o

  "_KalDataSourceChangedNotification", referenced from:
      _KalDataSourceChangedNotification$non_lazy_ptr in EventKitDataSource.o

     (maybe you meant: _KalDataSourceChangedNotification$non_lazy_ptr)


  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-EKEventViewController in FertilityAppAppDelegate.o
```

Comment: These seems like a you are referencing a objects that is no longer living. Without code is hard to tell but you can try Zombies Instrument or NSZombieEnabled (Which is basically the same)

Comment: already i added NSZombieEnabled - YES  but not getting in console.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added new static library to my application. Now working .

Comment: whats is this static library?

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you have added the EventKitUI.framework. If yes delete it and add it again.

Comment: after EventKit.framework delete and add it new the _OBJC_CLASS_$_EKEventViewController",  is cleared.

Comment: calendar in release mode i build  and i taken library then   added to my project. But i don't know the first two error is came . after once again i build and added new library there is no error , but i am not understand . plz explain me .